# How to assign a PHP variable from MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, variables, assign

I have a table as follows:

```
id name value
-------------
1  name john
```

I would like to pull name as a variable name and john as the value eg:

```
$name = "john";
```

I have tried saving the name as `$name` in the table but I can't use this to assign to the value.

I am thinking a `foreach` but just do not know how to construct it.

Comment: Take a look at Prepared Statements - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Could you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variable variables.

```
foreach ($db_results as $db_row) {
    ${$db_row->name} = $db_row->value;
}
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php